# Cocoa, objective c NIB loading two times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm loading a Nib which contains a preference window using:

```
 PreferenceWindowViewController *pref = [[PreferenceWindowViewController alloc] init];
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"PreferenceWindow" owner:pref];
```

But the problem is that the user could easily click on the "preferences option" in the menu bar (File -> Preferences) again without closing the current open preference window, i was thinking of a boolean variable to be set to true once the nib is opened, but was unsure how to re set the boolean variable to false (Nib not loaded) which exists in the main class when the close the window in the preference view controller class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just load the window once at app startup and then do:

```
[pref showWindow:nil];
```

every time the user clicks on your menu item. Wouldn't that be easier?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually how I do preferences. Your preferences controller class is custom NSWindowController subclass. In your main app controller, you create an instance variable for your prefs controller as shown below.

MDAppController.h:

```
@class MDPrefsController;

@interface MDAppController : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
     MDPrefsController  *prefsController;
}
- (IBAction)showPrefsWindow:(id)sender;
@end
```

MDAppController.m:

```
#import "MDAppController.h"
#import "MDPrefsController.h"

@implementation MDAppController
- (void)dealloc {
    [prefsController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)showPrefsWindow:(id)sender {
    if (prefsController == nil)
          prefsController = [[MDPrefsController alloc] init];
[prefsController showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

You have the Preferences menu item set to call a method like `-showPrefsWindow:`. In that method, you first check to see if your `prefsController` instance variable is `nil`, and if it is, you create it using alloc/init. (Note: an instance variable like `prefsController` here is automatically initialized to nil during `MDAppController`'s `-init` method). After assuring that the `prefsController` exists, you send it the standard `NSWindowController` method `-showWindow:`

MDPrefsController.h:

```
@interface MDPrefsController : NSWindowController <NSToolbarDelegate> {
    
}

@end
```

MDPrefsController.m:

```
#import "MDPrefsController.h"

@implementation MDPrefsController
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MDPrefs"])) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)showWindow:(id)sender {
    if (![[self window] isVisible]) {
        [[self window] center];
    }
    [[self window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
@end
```

So by making your `prefsController` an instance variable, you can check to make sure it's only created once. Also, the user is free to select Preferences from the application menu any time they want, and the result is the preference's window being brought forward.

[EDIT] I'll add more information on how this setup assures that only one copy of the preferences window is created.

First, we should clarify what the desired behavior should be when the user chooses the `Preferences…` menu item from the application menu. When the user chooses the prefs menu item, if the single prefs window is not currently shown, it should be made visible. If, on the other hand, the prefs window is already visible, then it should be brought forward. For the most part, this menu item should be enabled at all times. (In other words, even if the prefs window is currently being shown, the menu item is still enabled. When chosen, it merely brings the prefs window forward).

The code I posted accomplishes the goals set forth above by making `prefsController` an instance variable, and assuring that it's only created once. The `prefsController` is an instance of `MDPrefsController`, which is a subclass of `NSWindowController`. An `NSWindowController` manages a single window that is generally stored in a nib file. In your example, you were handling the nib-loading code in your main controller using `NSBundle`. In mine, I factor that out into the `MDPrefsController` class, which will load the "MDPrefs.nib" file as specified in its `-init` method. (`MDPrefsController` overrides `-init` to call `NSWindowController`'s [`-initWithWindowNibName:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004152)). That nib file contains the single window that the `MDPrefsController` manages.

The code shown below checks to make sure only that only a single instance of the `MDPrefsController` is ever created, and as such, assures that the MDPrefs.nib file, which contains the single preferences window, is only loaded once:

```
- (IBAction)showPrefsWindow:(id)sender {
    if (prefsController == nil)
          prefsController = [[MDPrefsController alloc] init];
[prefsController showWindow:self];
}
```

As a result, you assure that there's only a single copy of the prefs window.

[EDIT 2]: sample project at http://www.markdouma.com/developer/PreferencesWindow.zip

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, i need to make sure they can only have 1 copy of the preference window open at one time

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry, I don't understand how this wouldn't answer the question: How could the code I posted result in multiple copies of the preferences window being created? Note: I've updated the answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

just disable the File -> Preferences option, but not hide, until close the old one ,then enable that option.